# Unable to invoke Stored Procedure using Spring JDBC

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, spring-jdbc, complextype

We are unable to call a Stored Procedure using Spring JDBC. Below is the code snippet.

```
Procedure Signature

    PROCEDURE get_cash_details (
        p_org_id      IN      VARCHAR2,
        p_receipt_number  IN      VARCHAR2,
        p_result_type     IN      VARCHAR2,
        x_cash_detail     OUT     CASH_DETAIL_REC,
        x_error_msg   OUT     VARCHAR2
    );


The CASH_DETAIL_REC is of type STRUT returning a record type and 2 Arrays
```

Java Code  :

```
public void callStoredProcedure(String receiptNumber, String orgId, String type) {
    CashDetailsProcedure procedure = new CashDetailsProcedure(jdbcTemplate);
    procedure.execute();
}

public class CashDetailsProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public CashDetailsProcedure(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        super(jdbcTemplate, "BPEL_LLPOCWRAPPER.XX_AR_CASHRCPT_RCV_PKG$GET_CA ");


        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("P_ORG_ID", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("P_RECEIPT_NUMBER", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("P_RESULT_TYPE", Types.VARCHAR));

        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("X_CASH_DETAIL", OracleTypes.STRUCT, "XX_AR_CASHRCPT_RX3372075X1X4", new ReceiptHandler()));
            declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("X_ERROR_MSG", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));

            compile();   
    }

        public Map<String, Object> execute() {

            Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            inParams.put("P_ORG_ID", "204");
        inParams.put("P_RECEIPT_NUMBER", "89067");
        inParams.put("P_RESULT_TYPE", "Summary");
            Map output = execute(inParams);
            return output;
        }

}
```

Error Message :

```
CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
[{call BPEL_LLPOCWRAPPER.XX_AR_CASHRCPT_RCV_PKG$GET_CA (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; 
SQL state [null]; error code [17090]; operation not allowed: Ordinal binding
and Named binding cannot be combined!; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!
```

Comment: This call looks strange - {call BPEL_LLPOCWRAPPER.XX_AR_CASHRCPT_RCV_PKG$GET_CA (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} - shouldn't the procedure name be GET_CASH?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your response. We created a wrapper to overcome an error wrt to the length of the package name and procedure name. We were earlier getting an error stating the procedure name should be less than 30 characters. Also we have executed the Stored Procedure from SQL Prompt and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your simple query as

```
String query = "Select * from yourStoredProcedureName(?,?,?);"
```

and while calling using jdbcTemplate you can use two approach mapper or without mapper.
1> `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query,yourMapper, param1, param2, param3);`
2>

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, param1, param2, param3);
            for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
                System.out.println(row.get("firstName"));
}
```

the second method gives rows from there you can get the results for each result column.